# Cannot get SaveFileDialog to work with my web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, savefiledialog

I'm trying to add a method which uses a link from my grid view then gets the file from the server in the form of a Stream and then prompts the user where to save it. I've added the System.Windows.Forms reference to my controller and then added the following method.

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public void DownloadAssetStream(int assetID)
{
    //gStream created from server file.
    Stream myStream = gStream;
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "pdf files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
            if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                // Write file from stream.
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error but when code hits line `if (saveFileDialog1` it goes nowhere and dialog doesn't appear. What am I missing?

Comment: save file dialog is windows forms component. It won't work in asp.net page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of useful replies which showed how to return the file as a Stream but in order to display an Explorer window, this is not possible due to browser security. Anyone wanting to allow the User to define their own target location will have to suffice by using the browsers own download mechanism which downloads the file locally and then gives the user the option of where to save it to.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing that you can't use Windows controls in an ASP.NET application. It might work from Visual Studio but not in the real world.

Instead of trying to open a file dialog, send the result to the stream, for example using a [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
return new FileStreamResult(gStream, "application/pdf");
```

The second parameter is the content type, as example I've used the content type for PDF files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've been requested to prompt user with Windows  explorer window (like with the Fileupload component) to define where the download stream is to go. The above didn't do anything, how should I be calling DownloadAssetStream from my chtml razor file to get a window to define the target location for the stream?

Comment: That is something a browser determines, not you. You can access that action by a URL following the appropriate route.

Comment: You seem to missing the whole point, even if I return a file stream I need the user to determine where to save it. As it seems that because of Security most browsers wont allow an explorer style pop up I'm going to have to hook into the Browsers own way of downloading it and tell our project manager their request is not possible.

Comment: I think you see this wrong. You can't force browser to look on the hard drive where to store a file. A browser won't let you access that for security reasons. The only thing you can do is politely ask to download the file. If it shows a dialog and how is not to you. Send your project manager to me, I will explain it to him :)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but my previous message sums it up. I had already pretty much said the same and I've already explained to my Project manager that an Explorer style solution is not possible. We now have it working by hooking in to the Browsers own mechanism which shows the file downloading at the bottom of the screen and he is happy with that. Learnt something new today though :-)

Comment: You are welcome :) @user616076

Answer (score 0):

You can return `File` result in `action`

```
return File(gStream, "application/pdf", "DesiredNameToSave");
```

you need to change the return type of your action to `ActionResult` to handle all type of supported return values

```
public ActionResult DownloadAssetStream(int assetID)
```